# How to use Reduction Orders with decimal / non-integer quantities?

Tags: product, order, quotelineitem, orderitem

I'm considering using Reduction Orders to model the partial refund of an annual service. Example:

1. Create and Activate new Order A with one line, Quantity = 1, Price = $15000
2. Create and Activate Reduction Order B with one line, Quantity 0.5, Price = $7500

[image]

Unfortunately, Salesforce seems to take issue with non-integral Reduction Order Product Quantities. But this is inconsistent with the original order, which does normally accept non-integral quantities. One can get around this (once and once only) by inputting the Quantity as 1, then editing it to 0.5 (after which you get the above screenshot situation, where you are stuck with the first entered value)

There are a couple obvious angles:

- quantify months (12) instead of years (1)
- avoid reduction orders for the refund process
- deactivate and edit the original order to deal with refunds

But these seem very prescriptive on the business, or deviant from the intended use of the Original Order and Reduction Order models. Everything fits Salesforce except the non-integral quantity!

Is there something in Salesforce documentation about integral quantities? Other solutions?

Comment: Wait, what?! ***There is no positive integer less than or equal to 0***. That's a contradiction in terms.

Comment: :D :D That's what we said! @AdrianLarson

Comment: Did you open up a case on this one? I can only imagine how fun those conversations must be. That's a straight up bug given the error message, even if the actual validation is WAD.